# Angularjs 1.5: replace component tag with html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accessibility

I have an angular 1.5 app that makes extensive use of components. My issue is that the that my custom component tags are failing accessibility testing. My view model templates look like this:

```
<my-component data='myModel'></my-component>

<script type="text/ng-template" id=myComponent.html">
    <pre> {{ data | json }} </pre>
</script>
```

This will result in this rendered in the live DOM:

```
<my-component data='myModel'>
    <pre>
        ...
    </pre>
</my-component>
```

the my-component tag is not recognized by our testing tools and fails accessibility.

I have looked into transforming the my-component tags to divs, but cannot figure out how. Directives in 1.5 have the replace function. Components in 2.0 have the selector property. I don't believe I can achieve this using transclusion either (because it would my-component's controller would need to reference its parent tag).

Am I thinking about this the right way? Perhaps I should be using ng-Aria for screen readers to ignore these tags? Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: have you tried injecting $element into your controller and utilizing the angular.element APIs from there?

Comment: I've considered it, but not tried it. To me this would be a brute force method (turning my-component into a div) and have concerns that this may break angular functionality. I'd prefer to use something that angular provides if it exists.

Comment: I'd go with Eran's answer below then.  HTML5 and beyond should allow for custom tags and accessibility is woefully behind in most cases.  I'd see what his answer can do for you.

Comment: How did you fix this eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't change the element's tag,
but you should add aria tags natively when possible, or by angular aria.
Read [Angular accessibility guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/accessibility).